# Why do I only find iconimage instead of icon in JFrame properties [NetBeans]?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, icons, jframe

please help me, I'm new at Java programming, I want to add an image to my Jframe, so when I go to properties of my Jframe, i find 'iconIMAGE'.

And I can't find simply 'icon' like on most tutorials:

is it my netbean's Version or what?
And how can I get this icon property instead of iconImage?

what I find:
[image]

what I want:

[image]

Comment: IconImage is a wrapper for Icon which allows the image to be used whee either Icon or Image is required. Don't stress over it. Basically it's coming down to the same thing (there are some slight differences in painting, but you're a long way from having to worry about that)

Answer (score 1):

`JFrame` doesn't have an Icon property, it has an `IconImage` property as set by [setIconImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29). To add an icon in the frame area, you could just use an icon within a `JLabel`.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I actually did and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

Best way would be to do it pro grammatically (to actually learn programming):

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(path);

frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

where `path` is the path to your image file on the disk.